# cpf money in Singapore when Singapore PR expires

Tags: singapore, cpf

My Singapore PR has expired as I moved out of Singapore and I have relocated abroad. I am not planning to withdraw my CPF money for another 10 years and allow it to let it grow in Special account. My question is: Will my CPF money continue to earn interest in my account even though my SPR has expired? My thinking is, the CPF is separate from PR status. As long as I don't wish to withdraw my CPF amount, even if I'am not interested in applying for SPR again, I can retain my money in CPF account and can withdraw it any time. Can someone please clarify?

Answer (score 3):

CPF will not cancel your account or instruct the providers of your Special Account unless you specifically request them to do so.

If you are not Malaysian and residing in West Malaysia and then even so, withdrawal should be straight forward.

I suggest you email the the CPF board and clarify: member@cpf.gov.sg